# Python vs PHP regex

Tags: php, python, regex

I was working in Python using `re`. And now I want to port my code to PHP. So I ran into question: is there a `re.search("pattern", "string").start()` equalent in PHP?

Comment: take less time to ask google than post here

Comment: `re.search` is very ironic here.

Comment: @ultranaut, I don't use it in my code. But it is the same as `re.compile("pattern").search("string")`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading the manual or using a simple search engine.

Comment: @HamZa That doesn't mean that it's off-topic.

Comment: @Spooky I don't know about you, but Stackoverflow isn't a "code translator" service. Also it's totally useles for future visitors

Comment: @HamZa The criteria specified in your previous comment does not constitute a reason for this question to be considered off-topic. Read the Help Center [page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about this.

Comment: @Spooky That's an automatic message from the close vote I casted. The trick is that [stackoverflow changed the close-vote system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/) a while back, otherwise I would have choosed for `too localized`. I think this question should be closed, it's just a vote; a question needs 5 votes to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag.

> Searches `subject` for a match to the regular expression given in `pattern`.

Comment: I know about `preg_match`. But can I extract `start` from this command?

Comment: @Vik2015 You can read about `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`'s affect at the page I linked to.